# How to remove a bash script that runs at launch?

Tags: command-line, bash

I recently setup the following command:

```
echo “export DISPLAY=:0.0” >> ~/.bashrc
```

in my Ubuntu on windows distribution to save time on setting up the virtual desktop when I launch the program, but it doesn't ever work correctly when run at runtime, giving this:

```
Command '“export' not found, did you mean:

command 'mexport' from deb mblaze
```

This seems to be a result of the quotation marks that I used in the command from the guide that I followed, so I should be able to fix those by removing the quotes, but I need to remove the script first.

So I would like to remove it from running at launch, how would I go about this?

Comment: Looks like you used wrong kind of quotation marks. Are any quotation marks needed at all? Where did you find the command?

Comment: @pomsky I realized that, I had followed a guide to setup the desktop and it had the quotes, so that needs to be rectified when I try to set that up again. I don't think the quotes are needed from what I've seen about setting up commands like it, hence wanting to remove the command.

Comment: edit `~/.bashrc` manually and remove `"export...."`. `nano ~/.bashrc` should be simple enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the line

```
“export DISPLAY=:0.0”
```

in the file `.bashrc`.
The file would be in your user's home.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you used the character `“` and not the normal double quotes (`"`):

```
$ uniprops “
U+201C ‹“› \N{LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK}
    \pP \p{Pi}
    All Any Assigned Punct Is_Punctuation Common Zyyy Pi P General_Punctuation
       InPunctuation Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Initial_Punctuation
       Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax PatSyn Print X_POSIX_Print Punctuation QMark Quotation_Mark
       Unicode X_POSIX_Punct
$ uniprops \"
U+0022 ‹"› \N{QUOTATION MARK}
    \pP \p{Po}
    All Any ASCII Assigned Basic_Latin Punct Is_Punctuation Common Zyyy Po P Gr_Base
       Grapheme_Base Graph X_POSIX_Graph GrBase Other_Punctuation Pat_Syn Pattern_Syntax
       PatSyn POSIX_Graph POSIX_Print POSIX_Punct Print X_POSIX_Print Punctuation QMark
       Quotation_Mark Unicode X_POSIX_Punct
```

If you had used the regular quotes, it would have worked as you expected:

```
echo "export DISPLAY=:0.0" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Or

```
echo 'export DISPLAY=:0.0' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: or no quotes at all: `echo export DISPLAY=:0.0 >> ~/.bashrc` :)

Comment: @dessert indeed, in this case the quotes aren't needed, but it's good practice to use them anyway. Next time, you might want to do something like `echo "alias foo='ls bar*'" >> ~/.bashrc` for example and that would fail without the double quotes.